# Posts per row on archive page (custom post type)

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have problem with showing posts in more than one row, if I have more than 3 posts. How can I set more rows if I have more posts? For example, if I have 7 posts, I should have 3 rows. Can I do that? If yes, how?

```
<div class="row-fluid shop-products" >
    <ul class="thumbnails" >
    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="item span4" >
            <div class="thumbnail" id="archive_thumbnail">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="image">
                    <img src="<?php the_field( 'photo' ) ?>" alt="" id="archive_photo">
                    <span class="frame-overlay"></span>
                    <span class="price"><?php the_field( 'price_from' ) ?></span>
                </a>
                <div class="inner notop nobottom">
                    <h4 class="title"><?php the_field( 'title' )?></h4>
                    <p class="description"><?php the_field( 'content' ) ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner darken notop">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-add-to-cart">Add<i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the result if you have more than three posts?
what is the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use div instread of ul and li and make its width 1/3 of the row , or use count integer variable and make logic which insert row after integer divisible by 3.